# cron not able to run the commands in shell

Tags: shell, cron, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to run the following cron job from bash (RHEL 7.4), An entry level postgres DB backup script I could write:

```
    #!/bin/bash

# find latest file
echo $PATH
cd /home/postgres/log/

echo "------------ backup starts-----------"

latest_file=$( ls -t | head -n 1 | grep '\.log$' )

echo "latest file"
echo $latest_file

# find older files than above

echo "old file"

old_file=$( find . -maxdepth 1 -name "postgresql*" ! -newer $latest_file -mmin +1 )

if [ -f "$old_file" ]
        then
        echo $old_file

        file_name=${old_file##*/}

        echo "file name"
        echo $file_name

        # zip older file

        tar czvf /home/postgres/log/archived_logs/$old_file.gz  /home/postgres/log/$file_name

        rm -rf /home/postgres/log/$file_name

else
        echo "no old file found"
fi
```

Above is running correctly from shell and performing the intended tasks. It is also echoing needed info.
I have installed it with postgres user (not root) with crontab -e

```
*/2 * * * * /home/postgres/log/rollup.sh >> /home/postgres/log/logfile.csv 2>&1
```

It is correctly echoing (text which I have embedded for testing) but not the commands output to the .csv. Although it is not my concern. My concern is , it is not running those few commands at all.

I have given another try by changing the log file (.csv) path to /dev/null and commands in shell script are executing. I am not getting what I am missing here.

.csv file has 777 as permission , just to test

Comment: Which permission are set on /home/postgres/log/rollup.sh ? Maybe you did not add execute on others or group so it can be used only from the console open with your user.
Eventually I would give a try to set first a crontab job with
echo test > /home/postgres/log/test.csv to be sure crontab is working and the log folder is write-able

Comment: Thanks @P.Lion, here is the output of namei -om /home/postgres/log/rollup.sh:f: /home/postgres/log/rollup.sh
 dr-xr-xr-x root     root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root     root     home
 drwx------ postgres postgres postgres
 drwx------ postgres postgres log
 -rwx------ postgres postgres rollup.sh
Also , cron is running perfectly as it is echoing to the correct log file. Also when using /dev/null , it is even performing needed tasks